# Keyboard Navigation is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, treeview, keyboard-navigation

I have created a TreeViewComboBox control, in this I am having a ComboBox with items as TreeView, but Keyboard Navigation doesn't work on the TreeView. I am not able to navigate through the TreeViewItems using keyboard. Any help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has a similar issue when implementing our property grid control. The issue in *our* specific, which **could** be similar to yours, was that the keyboard focus events were not routing to the `TreeViewItem`.

The way we solved it was by adding an AttachedProperty to the TreeViewItem style and *selecting* the node when it gets keyboard focus. I implemented this using a *Service* pattern. See below:

**In XAML:**

```
<Style x:Key="EditorBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Controls_Services:TreeViewItemService.SelectWhenKeyboardIsFocused" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

**In Codebehind:**

```
  public class TreeViewItemService
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectWhenKeyboardIsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectWhenKeyboardIsFocused",
      typeof(bool), typeof(TreeViewItemService), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, TreeViewItemService.OnSelectWhenKeyboardIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

    static void OnSelectWhenKeyboardIsFocusedPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
      if (element == null)
        return;

      TreeViewItem target = MTVisualTreeHelper.FindParent<TreeViewItem>(element as DependencyObject);
      if (target != null)
        new IsSelectedOnKeyboardFocusAction(element, target);
    }

    public static bool GetSelectWhenKeyboardIsFocused(FrameworkElement target)
    {
      return (bool)target.GetValue(SelectWhenKeyboardIsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectWhenKeyboardIsFocused(FrameworkElement target, bool value)
    {
      target.SetValue(SelectWhenKeyboardIsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    private class IsSelectedOnKeyboardFocusAction
    {
      TreeViewItem m_Target;
      FrameworkElement m_Source;

      public IsSelectedOnKeyboardFocusAction(FrameworkElement source, TreeViewItem item)
      {
        m_Source = source;
        m_Target = item;
        m_Source.Loaded += OnSource_Loaded;
        m_Source.Unloaded += OnSource_Unloaded;
      }

      void OnSource_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        m_Source.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        m_Source.GotFocus += OnSource_GotFocus;
        m_Source.LostFocus += OnSource_LostFocus;
        m_Source.GotKeyboardFocus += OnSource_GotKeyboardFocus;
        m_Source.LostKeyboardFocus += OnSource_LostKeyboardFocus;
      }

      void OnSource_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        m_Source.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        m_Source.GotFocus -= OnSource_GotFocus;
        m_Source.LostFocus -= OnSource_LostFocus;
        m_Source.GotKeyboardFocus -= OnSource_GotKeyboardFocus;
        m_Source.LostKeyboardFocus -= OnSource_LostKeyboardFocus;
      }

      void OnSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
        if (!m_Target.IsSelected)
          m_Target.IsSelected = true;
      }

      void OnSource_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (!m_Target.IsSelected)
          m_Target.IsSelected = true;
      }

      void OnSource_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (m_Target.IsSelected)
          m_Target.IsSelected = false;
      }

      void OnSource_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (!m_Target.IsSelected)
          m_Target.IsSelected = true;
      }

      void OnSource_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (m_Target.IsSelected)
          m_Target.IsSelected = false;
      }

    }

  }
```

HTH,